# hMailServer forwarding and distribution lists with SPF checking

Tags: email, spam, spf, email-server

I have installed and configured hMailServer, primarily to allow me to create a distribution list for a private organisation, and some email address aliases.

This is so that members of the organisation can send email to a managed list of all the members, and also have nice short email addresses (such as fred@mydomain.com instead of fred.123.mysurname@whateveremailprovider.com).

It's all setup and working, and I've configured DKIM and SPF records.

However, when I send an email to fred@mydomain.com, which forwards it on to a gmail address, I can see an error in the headers (even though the email does actually get delivered):

```
spf=hardfail (google.com: domain of fred@mydomain.com does not designate 1.2.3.4 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=fred@mydomain.com
```

I can understand why, because the origin of the email is from a different server than my hMailServer.

How can I fix this so that it passes the SPF check? or if I can't fix it, then would this eventually have any impact on Google eventually marking the emails as spam? What can I do about it?

Answer (score 3):

SPF does not work well with email forwarding.

The receiving server (Gmail in this case) verifies that the IP address of the SMTP server sending it the mail is authorised in the SPF record of the sender address's domain.  If you have a forwarding server (hmailserver in this case) in the middle, it's unlikely that server's IP address is going to be configured in the SPF record of all senders that go through it.

In the specific test case where you're sending the test email from an account you own, you could of course update your own SPF record to include the hMailServer IP address, but that is only masking the problem, because third parties sending email will still show up as SPF fail.

[Sender Rewriting Scheme (SRS)](http://www.openspf.org/SRS) was created as a way to solve this problem.  However, hMailServer doesn't support it.  ([Forum thread](http://www.hmailserver.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=11698))

If you can find a free Windows mail server that supports SRS, that would hopefully solve your problem. (And if you do, please let me know)